# How can I display php fetch _assoc results vertically in html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have html/mysql query results page that displays a header row with 3 columns and the one record in the row under the header row. If it was just html i can do it, but with the mysql fetch assoc code, I am not sure how.

Currently it display the search result like this:

Address       City        ST

17 King      new york      ny

I want to display the result vertically like this:

Address | 17 King St.
City |  New York
ST  |  New York

Here is the code:

```
 $query = "(SELECT * FROM test where id='$id')";
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Address</th>
 <th>City</th>
 <th>State</th>
 </tr>";

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Comment: What is your wanted results with more data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query return just a line, then change your table format so:

```
 echo "<table border='1'>";

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>Adress: </td><td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>City: </td><td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>State: </td><td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
```

In your request type, you don't have header, so don't need < th > tag

If your request return more than one line, even for same Id, then you must declare the table row in while condition, same for close. This will create one table row for each line of your query. Or just add one empty line in your table, after each adress:

```
Echo "<tr></tr>"
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked. I just had to add <tr> and </tr> tags for each line to your code so that each name/value pair appeared on a different row to make it vertical. That was all you were missing.

Comment: Errm, so why did you accept this answer if it doesn't not actually demonstrate how to perform the technique properly?  Now I can't use this page to close a new duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one row in your query result, You can try

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM test where id='$id')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo "<table border='1'>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr><th>Address</th><td>" . $row['address'] . "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><th>City</th><td>" . $row['city'] . "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><th>State</th><td>" . $row['state'] . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Finally, a correct answer which puts each value as its own rows!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

Store data in arrays :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $addresses[] = $row['address'] ;
    $cities[] = $row['city'] ;
    $states[] = $row['state'] ;
}
```

Then display results :

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Address</th>';
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    echo '<td>' . $address . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>City</th>';
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    echo '<td>' . $city . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

// ...etc.
```